# О наименовании числительных

Tags: числительные

Лингвист пишет: "Х. Фаизханов выделяет три разряда имен числительных: количественные, порядочные и разделительные".
Действительно ли у лингвистов есть такое наименование числительных "порядочные", или это просто ошибка и должно быть "порядковые"?
Фаизханов писал это в конце 19-го века. Может быть, тогда вместо "порядковые" писали "порядочные"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведу данные из [диссертации](http://cheloveknauka.com/kolichestvennye-chislitelnye-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke) (М. Н. Приемышева. Количественные числительные в современном русском языке):

Впервые термин "имя числительное" для обозначения одной из частей речи ("частей слова") русского языка употребил в "Российской грамматике" М. Ломоносов. В отдельную часть речи (не в системе имени, куда относили числительное М. Ломоносов, А. Барсов, Грамматика Российская Академии наук 1802 г.) выделил Г. Павский [Павский 1850].
И если М. Ломоносов основные разряды числительных определял еще как "первообразные" и "производные", а А. Барсов — "как "основательные", "порядочные", "разделительные", "умножительные" и др., то в Академической грамматике 1802 г. употреблены термины "количественные" и "порядочные" (Ф. Буслаев — "порядковые") имена числительные, которые прочно закрепились в дальнейшей лингвистической традиции.

---

Хусаин Фаизханов (1823–**1866**).
В [Учебнике русской грамматики](https://www.prlib.ru/item/388956) (Сост. Ф. Буслаев. — 4-е изд., испр. — Москва : Унив. тип. (Катков и К°), **1874**), на стр. 89:
5. Имя числительное.
§82. Числительные имена различаются по значению и по составу.
По значению они бывают количественные и порядковые.

Думаю, что приблизительно в это время и произошло "переименование" *порядочных* числительных в *порядковые*.

Comment: *Думаю, что приблизительно в это время и произошло "переименование" порядочных числительных в порядковые.* - Применительно к русскому языку, думаю, раньше. В приведенном фрагменте автор явно имеет в виду татарский язык, где существуют разделительные числительные.

Comment: Я чисто интуитивно ориентировалась на даты: 1802 - ещё порядочные; 1874 - уже порядковые. Х. Фаизханов умер в 1866. Я предполагаю, что изменение произошло ~ в середине века. Спасибо за оценку.

Comment: Фазиханов  - да, это автор XIX века, a Барсов, который, судя по всему, и был последним, кто употреблял термин "порядочные" применительно к РЯ жил в XVIII (1730-1791). Вот я и ориентируюсь на начало XIX. Естественно, что моё мнение сугубо оценочное. но оно все-то не совсем субъективно....

Answer (score 1):

Числительные делятся на четыре лексико-грамматических разряда: количественные (два, пятьдесят, двести, триста пятьдесят один) и собирательные (оба, двое, пятеро) — отвечают на вопрос сколько?, порядковые — отвечают на вопрос который? (первый, второй, сотый), дробные (одна пятая, три целых, две седьмых).

https://studopedia.ru/20_20690_klassifikatsiya-chislitelnih-po-znacheniyu-schetnie-slova.html

Answer (score 1):

> Фаизханов писал это в конце 19-го века. Может быть, тогда вместо
>   "порядковые" писали "порядочные"?

Именно так. Только не "писали", а называли.
Это терминология середины позапрошлого века, причем она применялась, насколько помню, по большей части именно к тюрксксим языкам, где "порядочные" противопоставлялись "разделительным" - последние вообще известны только тюркским.

В русском языке числительные этого разряда ("порядковые") назывались "порядочными" только некоторое время - на этапе становления терминологии и систематики вообще (до начала 18 века), слово "порядок" тогда не имело нынешней формы прилагательного "порядковый".

Ни в современном русском языке, ни в общей лингвистике термином "порядочные числительные" специалисты не оперируют.

Что касается общих сведений о числительных в русском, вам их дали, не буду повторять.